# Thymeleaf - Flatten form fields

Tags: java, thymeleaf

I'm trying to create a PDF and make some checkboxes not editable, else they can be changed and that's not what I need.

I tried using
`<input type="checkbox" id="randomId" th:checked="true" readonly="readonly"/>`, but it's not working, tried to disable it, but still not working. Any suggestions?

Comment: Could we get a [mcve] please?

Answer (score 0):

Use `disabled` instead of `readonly`. `readonly` only affects the editable text value of a field - whereas a checkbox has a *state* not an editable value.

You don't actually need any specific Thymeleaf variables for this. You can just use the following plain HTML in your Thymeleaf template:

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="randomId" disabled checked>
```

---

If you do want to use Thymeleaf expressions, you can use this:

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="randomId" th:disabled="${true}" th:checked="${true}">
```

These are Thymeleaf [boolean attributes](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf#fixed-value-boolean-attributes).

I would just use plain HTML.

Comment: Hello, as I said in my question, disabled is not working.

Comment: "_tried to disable it_" - Can you show us _how_ you are using `disabled`? As you can see from the runnable demo in this answer, it works for plain HTML. If that is not working for you, then we need you to create an equivalent runnable demo in your question, showing us how `disabled` does not work for you (or if you still want to use Thymeleaf expressions, at least show us the relevant Java code and Thymeleaf code that we can copy and paste and test for ourselves).

Comment: "_trying to create a PDF_" - And if this turns out to be a PDF-related problem, then there are no details in the question about anything relating to how you are creating your PDF. So, we would need to see all those relevant details, also. It is much harder for us to help you to fix your problem if we cannot recreate your problem for ourselves.

Answer (score 0):

To make checkboxes not editable, you can use the disabled attribute instead of readonly. The disabled attribute prevents the user from interacting with the element altogether, while readonly allows the user to see the current value of the checkbox, but they cannot change it.

So, your code should look something like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="randomId" checked="checked" disabled="disabled"/>
```

This will create a checkbox that is initially checked and cannot be changed by the user.

Comment: Hello, as I said in my question, I already tried to disable it that way, but it's not working.